# How to dynamically create local variables in main

Tags: ruby

How to define variables in main binding of plain ruby file?

I have tried TOPLEVEL_BINDING, but its dont share variables to main scope

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# ....

5.times do |i|
  src = %(
    reader#{i} = library.create_reader "name"
    book#{i}   = library.create_book   "title"
  )
  TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval(src)
end

3.times { reader0.take(book0) } # error
5.times { reader1.take(book1) }
1.times { reader2.take(book2) }
0.times { reader3.take(book3) }
1.times { reader4.take(book4) }

puts book0.title
```

Comment: I wonder why you want to do that? Wouldn't it be easier to use an array or a hash to store the objects and read from it?

Comment: Since Ruby v1.8 it has not been possible to create local variables dynamically. (It can be done in v1.8 with `eval`.)

Comment: @spickermann want my code to resemble rspec)

Comment: @CarySwoveland so theres no way to do this with local variables?

Comment: I confess I don't fully understand your question. You could do the following if it would help: `b = binding; b.local_variable_set :cat_lives, 9; b.eval "cat_lives" #=> 9`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I want to access `cat_lives` without b.eval, I want dinamically create variables in other methods and access them like I simply wrote `reader0 = library.create_reader "name"` in main scope

Comment: I can dinamically create methods with name `reader0` and so on and I will have effect like I want, but can I do this with local variables? **It look like [isolated eval](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6710) feature can permint this**, but it not accepted

Comment: Yes, you can dynamically create methods and instance variables ([#instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set)), but not local variables. Would instance variables work?

Comment: What you're trying to do is easily possible in other language, and at one time was considered an OK practice, however these days it's frowned on. You're generating variables that are "invisible" unless you analyze the code closely. That leads to bugs and very hard to maintain code. Ruby has other ways of doing it, and in some situations they're acceptable, but you should try to not do this until you're very familiar with when it's OK and when it's not.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, in answers. Maybe I must accept this as feature

Comment: @theTinMan ok, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define instance variables dynamically :

```
5.times do |i|
  instance_variable_set(:"@reader#{i}", "library_name#{i}")
  instance_variable_set(:"@book#{i}", "book_title#{i}")
end

puts @reader1
puts @book1
puts @book4

# => library_name1
#    book_title1
#    book_title4
```

Another possibility would be to use method_missing to fake local variables, while using instance variables as cache :

```
def create_variable_or_use_cache(name, &block)
  name = "@#{name}"
  instance_variable_get(name) || instance_variable_set(name, block.yield)
end

def method_missing(sym,*p)
  if sym=~/^reader(\d+)$/ then
    create_variable_or_use_cache(sym){ "Create reader#{$1} here" }
  elsif sym=~/^book(\d+)$/ then
    create_variable_or_use_cache(sym){ "Create book#{$1} here" }
  else
    super
  end
end

puts reader1
puts reader1
puts book3
wrong_method

# => 
# Create reader1 here
# Create reader1 here
# Create book3 here
# binding.rb:13:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method   `wrong_method' for main:Object (NameError)
```

It's an interesting Ruby exercise, I'm not sure you should use it though.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without explicitely using binding. The question is also if you should do it ;)